# CJK Strings on .bat file

Tags: batch-file, replace, cmd, utf, cjk

I recently found this piece of code to replace certain parts of a file and I want to automate the process.

So the code is this:

```
@echo off
REM -- Prepare the Command Processor --
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

::BatchSubstitude - parses a File line by line and replaces a substring"
::syntax: BatchSubstitude.bat OldStr NewStr File
::          OldStr [in] - string to be replaced
::          NewStr [in] - string to replace with
::          File   [in] - file to be parsed
::$changed 20100115
::$source https://www.dostips.com
chcp 65001

if "%~1"=="" findstr "^::" "%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type %3|find /n /v """') do (
    set "line=%%B"
    if defined line (
        call set "line=echo.%%line:%~1=%~2%%"
        for /f "delims=" %%X in ('"echo."%%line%%""') do %%~X
    ) ELSE echo.
)
```

I added chcp 65001 to support UTF8.

I call the BatchSubstitute.bat file with a start.bat file:

```
chcp 65001
set "nombreAPasar=いとうかなこ - ファティマ.m3u8"
BatchSubstitute.bat ".flac" .wav %nombreAPasar%
```

What I want to do and you probably have guessed is convert the ".flac" into ".wav" strings on the playlist file いとうかなこ - ファティマ.m3u8, which text is:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:246,いとうかなこ - ファティマ
01 - ファティマ - ファティマ.flac
#EXTINF:277,いとうかなこ - はじまりの歌
02 - ファティマ - はじまりの歌.flac
#EXTINF:303,いとうかなこ - 宿業ノ剣
03 - ファティマ - 宿業ノ剣.flac
#EXTINF:246,いとうかなこ - ファティマ(off vocal)
04 - ファティマ - ファティマ(off vocal).flac
#EXTINF:271,いとうかなこ - はじまりの歌(off vocal)
05 - ファティマ - はじまりの歌(off vocal).flac
#EXTINF:302,いとうかなこ - 宿業ノ剣(off vocal)
06 - ファティマ - 宿業ノ剣(off vocal).flac
```

And it throws me this error:

```
D:(Path)>start.bat

D:(Path)>chcp 65001
Página de códigos activa: 65001

D:(Path)>set "nombreAPasar=いとうかなこ - ファティマ.m3u8"

D:(Path)>BatchSubstitute.bat ".flac" .wav いとうかなこ - ファティマ.m3u8
Página de códigos activa: 65001
El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.
```

Only meaningful thing here is last line, meaning: `The system coulnd't find the specified file` and it is thrown by the `in ('"type %3|find /n /v """') do` part of the BatchSubstitute file (I know this because I executed it without @echo off)

If you want full output:

```
D:(path)>start.bat

D:(path)>chcp 65001
Página de códigos activa: 65001

D:(path)>set "nombreAPasar=いとうかなこ - ファティマ.m3u8"

D:(path)>BatchSubstitute.bat ".flac" .wav いとうかなこ - ファティマ.m3u8

D:(path)>REM -- Prepare the Command Processor --

D:(path)>SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS

D:(path)>SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

D:(path)>chcp 65001
Página de códigos activa: 65001

D:(path)>if ".flac" == "" findstr "^::" "D:\Users\Alonso\Desktop\RIPSteinsGate\FLAC\WAV\BatchSubstitute.bat"  & GOTO:EOF

D:(path)>for /F "tokens=1,* delims=]" %A in ('"type いとうかなこ|find /n /v """') do (
set "line=%B"
 if defined line (
call set "line=echo.%line:.flac=.wav%"
 for /F "delims=" %X in ('"echo."%line%""') do %~X
)  ELSE echo.
)
El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.
```

So I tried multiple ways to pass the complete string to the script but no one worked for me. I think there is the error.

The CMD in reality does show ? with a square around them, but the thing is it understands it, so no problem there, (also the text pasted is directly copied from the CMD).

Would it be any solution or other script which does the same in a working way?
Thank you in advance.

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

UPDATE:
I just modified both of my .bat and it seems like progress:

start.bat

```
chcp 65001
set "nombreAPasar="いとうかなこ - ファティマ.m3u8""
BatchSubstitute.bat ".flac" .wav %nombreAPasar%
```

BatchSubstitute.bat

```
 (just put that :: to give you info)::@echo off
    REM -- Prepare the Command Processor --
    SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
    SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

    ::BatchSubstitude - parses a File line by line and replaces a substring"
    ::syntax: BatchSubstitude.bat OldStr NewStr File
    ::          OldStr [in] - string to be replaced
    ::          NewStr [in] - string to replace with
    ::          File   [in] - file to be parsed
    ::$changed 20100115
    ::$source https://www.dostips.com
    chcp 65001

    if "%~1"=="" findstr "^::" "%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type %~3|find /n /v """') do (
        set "line=%%B"
        if defined line (
            call set "line=echo.%%line:%~1=%~2%%"
            for /f "delims=" %%X in ('"echo."%%line%%""') do %%~X
        ) ELSE echo.
    )
```

New errors returned are:

```
D:(path)>if ".flac" == "" findstr "^::" "(path)"  & GOTO:EOF

D:(path)>for /F "tokens=1,* delims=]" %A in ('"type いとうかなこ - ファティマ.m3u8|find /n /v """') do (
set "line=%B"
 if defined line (
call set "line=echo.%line:.flac=.wav%"
 for /F "delims=" %X in ('"echo."%line%""') do %~X
)  ELSE echo.
)
El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.
Error mientras se procesaba: いとうかなこ.
El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.
Error mientras se procesaba: -.
El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.
Error mientras se procesaba: ファティマ.m3u8.
```

NOTE THAT:

```
El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado. == System couldn't find specified file
```

and

```
Error mientras se procesaba: いとうかなこ. == Error while processing: ---
```

Comment: You could start by doublequoting your `File [in]` i.e. `BatchSubstitute.bat ".flac" ".wav" "%nombreAPasar%"`

Comment: I would also change `%3` to `"%~3"` to handle quoting better. It appears there are space characters on each side of the `-` between the kana.

Comment: I am not so sure about using `CHCP 65001`. Is your .bat file script UTF-8 or codepage 932?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, finally did it. 
In this line of BatchSubstitute .bat I changed

```
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type %~3|find /n /v """') do (
```

by

```
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type "%~3"|find /n /v """') do (
```

And removed the `chcp 65001` because it was written to the output file, being eecuted only on the calling .bat and not the called one.

And also changed the start.bat to:

```
chcp 65001 set "nameFile="いとうかなこ - ファティマ.m3u8""
call BatchSubstitute.bat ".flac" ".wav" %nameFile% > temp.temp
del %nameFile%
rename temp.temp %nameFile%
```

I leave it here if you want it working.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jRVaI3UJEXLRKxzd_YNZEwGD3c-kL1z2/view?usp=sharing

Also note that .bat file is encoded in UTF-8 without BOM.